# php/regex - Extract proper nouns from text

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract proper nouns (e.g Micheal Jackson) from a text with PHP regex but my regex is not right.

The text:

> My friend Micheal Jackson was the King of Pop. The Game Album sold little.

What I want:

A regex that is able to extract proper nouns of multiple words e.g Micheal Jackson or The Game Album.

My regex:

```
/(?<=\s)([A-Z][a-z]+).*(?=\s)/
```

Thanks.

P.S. Posted via a mobile device. Apologies if format is poor.

Comment: Regex doesn't know what a proper name is. How do you define/find them?

Comment: Michael. Just in case spelling matters to your algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use word boundaries instead of your lookbehind/lookahead

```
/\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b/
```

I don't understand your `.*` part this will match anything after the first word till the last whitespace, so I removed it from my regex.

If you want to match multiple words at once (Maybe you wanted to achieve this with your `.*`?) try this:

```
(?:\s*\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b)+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uqts)

Comment: +1 for the succinct `(?:\s*\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b)+` regex.  What about proper nouns that have capitals in the middle of a single word (for example, a company name like 'CompuServe')?  Maybe you should consider using `(?:\s*\b([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)\b)+` instead.

Comment: For proper nouns like "iPhone" that start with a lowercase letter, but have a capital in them I use: (?:\s*\b([a-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)\b)+

Comment: FYI: That'll will match white space preceeding whitespace before a single capitalized word.

Answer (score 1):

The Stanford Parser can help you here. It will tokenize your phrase and extract proper nouns and all other pieces according to the sentence structure.

It's available as a jar download or you can try it out online here:  http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/